# Stop Live reloading of React app on other machune

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I and my friend is developing and testing React app in parallel. He is accessing app running locally on my machine through my machine Ip address. But the problem is whenever I implement something in code and hit save app reloads on mine as well as his machine. I want to stop reloading of app on my friend's machine so that he can test app easily in parallel. If he wants to update data in his app he could be able to do it by manually reloading.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use request blocking feature of chrome

[image]

add this url

> localhost:3000/sockjs-node/*

in request blocking from your friend PC.